# Can I access the contents of an Ender chest in the home world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I made an Ender Chest in my Home Server where I live, and another Ender Chest in the End, will an item placed in it go to my house server?

I placed the Dragon egg in the Ender chest, and I want to know if that item can go to my home server while I'm in another server from the End.

Comment: This actually isn't THAT unclear, but it'd be nice if you could clarify between what you mean by saves (are you talking about end and overworld on same server/save file or are you talking about a server and another server?), as the answer changes between those two.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, ender chests will save items across different worlds. If by "home server" you mean your home is on an entirely different save (i.e. different world folders) then it will not appear there (unless the multi-server system supports this). However if this is just single player it will save your items in your ender chest, in fact it's a useful way to take extra items to the end :)